# Spring boot 2.2.8.RELEASE compatible java version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17

Is Spring boot version "2.2.8.RELEASE" supports java 17?

Comment: No it doesn't. 2.6 and upwards do.

Answer (score 2):

No, Spring boot officially started supporting Java 17 from version 2.5.3

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.5.3